# maximising a linear model function with unknowns

Tags: r, regression, self-study, maximum-likelihood, extreme-value

If i have this linear model
$$Y_{i,t}=\gamma_t(x_i)+v_{i,t}, v_{i,t} \stackrel{iid}{\sim}N(0,\sigma^2), i=1,\ldots,m.$$
$$\gamma_t(x)=\beta_{1,t}+\beta_{2,t}\frac{1-e^{-\lambda x}}{ \lambda x}+ \beta_{3,t}\left( \frac{1-e^{- \lambda x}}{\lambda x}-e^{-\lambda x}\right)$$
Assume that

```
x= c(3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,30,36,48,60,72,84,96,108,120)
y = c(5.371,5.398,5.430,5.541,5.625,5.657,5.697,5.750,5.756,5.817,5.869,5.978,5.985,6.082,6.147,6.270,6.342,6.318)
```

Now, I wanted to establish the value of lambda that maximises this function out of the following 500 values

```
lambda = seq(0.1,1.5,length.out = 500)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  And please add the self-study tag to homework or self-study problems; we won't do your homework for you, after all!

Comment: I have built a linear model. h2 <- function(x){(1-exp(-lambda*x))/(lambda*x)}
h3 <- function(x){((1-exp(-lambda*x))/(lambda*x)) - exp(-lambda*x)}, so basically evaluated h2(x)=a and h3(x)=b then fitted a lm(y~h2(x)+h3(x)). However, I $\lambda$ to be 0.069. However, I wanted to generalise this model and repeatedely test other values of lambda

Answer (score 1):

You have the right general idea for how to approach the problem: split it into an outer step involving $\lambda$ and an inner step where you find the optimal estimates of $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ conditional upon $\lambda$.  There is a faster way of doing it than testing different values of $\lambda$, namely, directly finding the optimum value of $\lambda$ using a general-purpose optimization routine.

I assume your objective is to minimize the residual sum of squared errors from the initial regression.

We can set this up in R as follows:

```
foo <- function(lambda, y, x) {
   h1 <- (1-exp(-lambda*x))/(lambda*x)
   h2 <- h1 - exp(-lambda*x)
   model <- lm(y~h1+h2)
   summary(model)$sigma 
}

res <- optimise(foo, interval=c(0.1,1.5), y=y, x=x)
```

I had to remove the last `y` value as the sample vectors you provided were not the same length, but since this is just an example it doesn't matter.  The result is:

```
> res
$minimum
[1] 0.1000519

$objective
[1] 0.07031441
```

This indicates that the minimizing value of $\lambda = 0.1$.  To see what the relationship between $\lambda$ and $\hat{\sigma}$ (the estimated standard deviation of the residuals) is, we can generate a plot of same:

```
lambda <- seq(0.1,1.5,by=0.01)
sigma <- rep(0, length(lambda))
for (i in seq_len(length(lambda))) {
   sigma[i] <- foo(lambda[i], y, x)
}

plot(sigma~lambda)
```

which looks like:

[image]

Comment: Hi jbowman, thank you for your response. I justed wanted to ask a few questions.Firstly, what is that you have maximized against sigma? Let's assume I take lambda to 0.1, by the way my choice of 0.1 to 1.5 is completely random. Is there is a way I can calculate the confidence intervals of lambda, I'm guessing I need a standard error of lambda but am not sure of how I could obtain this.

Comment: We aren't maximizing in this sort of modeling, we are minimizing, in this case, the standard deviation of the residuals.  The idea is that a better fit is one with smaller errors, and it's mathematically very convenient if we measure "smaller errors" by their variance.  As it happens, minimizing their variance is equivalent to minimizing their standard deviation.  I'll add a section on finding confidence intervals etc. later on.

Comment: ok yes. thanks for the explanation. Any guidance on the confidence intervals would be fantastic, thanks.